# wicket orderdrop down

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, wicket

In the top of my page I want a dropdown to change the preferred language. If it alters the page is to be reloaded and rendered with the selected langauge.
In my solution the language is not loaded immediately though.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CurrentLanguageDropdown extends LanguageDropDown {

private String sessionlanguage;
private IModel<String> model;

public CurrentLanguageDropdown(String id, Locale locale) {
    super(id, locale);
    this.sessionlanguage = locale.getCountry();
    GlobalAccountSession session = GlobalAccountSession.get();
    model = new SelectedLocaleModel("sessionlanguage", this, new     Model<Serializable>(session.getLocale()),
            locale.getCountry());
    setModel(model);
}

@Override
public void onSelectionChanged(String newSelection) {
    GlobalAccountSession session = GlobalAccountSession.get();
    model = new SelectedLocaleModel("sessionlanguage", this, new Model<Serializable>(session.getLocale()),
            newSelection);
}

@Override
protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
    return true;
}

String getSessionlanguage() {
    return sessionlanguage;
}

private class SelectedLocaleModel extends StringResourceModel {

    private String selectedValue = "";
    private Component parent;

    public SelectedLocaleModel(String resourceKey, Component parent, IModel<?> model, String selectedValue) {
        super(resourceKey, parent, model);
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void setObject(java.lang.String object) {
        GlobalAccountSession session = GlobalAccountSession.get();
        Locale locale = new Locale(object.toString());
        session.setLocale(locale);
        selectedValue = locale.getLanguage();
    }

    @Override
    public String getObject() {
        GlobalAccountSession session = GlobalAccountSession.get();
        selectedValue = session.getLocale().getLanguage();
        return selectedValue;
    }
}
}
```

Looking at my code I see that getObject is called first, and setObject after that. So rendering seems to be done before the change made by the user is handled.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Im not really sure why your using the model at all. I would make the dropdown use a list of locales and then when onSelectionChanged is called, add the selected one to your session.

Comment: The model is used because  the supported languages are loaded from a backend system

Comment: but wouldn't you need a Model<list<Locales>> in that case. Then add a setSessionlanguage() method, you then wouldn't have to create your own model. Also make the SessionLanguage a Locale object instead of a string. If you worried about the dropdown rendering the object id now, because SessionLanguage is a Locale, use a ChoiceRenderer to display the correct info.

Comment: because of wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications, so that page is reloaded at change of dropdown value, I get error if no model is set. I got the error: Attempt to set model object on null model of component: header.panel:session.language. So that's why I added the model.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new model object in onSelectionChanged. This defeats the purpose of a model which should be modified but not replaced. If you need to create a new model object, you'll have to replace the model used by your component too (call setModel(model) again).

Answer (score 0):

I know this isnt a component but an implementation of one but shows the general idea

```
public class LocaleDropDownPanel extends Panel
{
private Locale sessionLocale;

public LocaleDropDownPanel(String id, Locale locale) 
{
    super(id);


    ArrayList<Locale> choices = Lists.newArrayList(Locale.getAvailableLocales());

    //didnt know if you need country or language 
    IChoiceRenderer<Locale> choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<Locale>("language");

    DropDownChoice<Locale> ddc = new DropDownChoice<Locale>("ddc", new PropertyModel<Locale>(this, "sessionLocale"), 
            new Model<ArrayList<Locale>>(choices), choiceRenderer)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onSelectionChanged(Locale newSelection) 
        {
             //if you want to save the selected locale in your session.
             GlobalAccountSession session = GlobalAccountSession.get();
             session.setLocale(newSelection);
        }
    };

    //This Language selected to begin with
    ddc.setDefaultModelObject(locale);

}

public Locale getSessionLocale() {
    return sessionLocale;
}

public void setSessionLocale(Locale sessionLocale) {
    this.sessionLocale = sessionLocale;
}
}
```